# How to use Any with Flask-Enterprise

Tags: python, soap

I can't find any examples or documentation for using Any with Flask-Enterprise when creating a SOAP service. It is mentioned briefly in the [Soap Models section of the documentation](http://massive.immersedcode.org/2011/staging/projects/default/python/flask-enterprise/#soap-modelling) but, unlike the other types described in that section, there is no code block showing its usage.

Maybe I am going down a rabbit hole even trying to use Flask-Enterprise since, if you go to their home page, it says they have been bought out and no longer license their software to 3rd party developers.

Answer (score 0):

Try flask-spyne extension, it's BSD licensed.